# Getting a value from ComboBox

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a combo-box via VBA code.

```
Sub CreateFormControl()

ActiveSheet.DropDowns.Add(0, 0, 100, 15).Name = "ComboBox1"
ActiveSheet.Shapes("ComboBox1").ControlFormat.RemoveAllItems

Dim i As Integer
With ActiveSheet.Shapes("ComboBox1").ControlFormat
    For i = 1 To 25
        .AddItem i
    Next i
End With
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("ComboBox1")).Select
Selection.OnAction = "ComboBox1_Change"
Range("B2").Select

End Sub
```

The problem here is, when I select an item in the `ComboBox`, it gives me a

> Run-time error 424. Object required

It doesn't show the value selected. I also tried to change my declaration, `Sub CreateFormControl()` to Public `Sub CreateFormControl()`, but it's still not working.

```
Sub ComboBox1_Change()

MsgBox (ComboBox1.Value) 'The error is here

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below, try to replace `ActiveSheet` with a qualifed `Worksheet`, like `Worksheets("YoutSheetName")`.

```
Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim MyDropDown As DropDown

' try not to use ActiveSheet, replace "Sheet1" with your sheet's name
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1") ' ActiveSheet
Set MyDropDown = ws.Shapes("ComboBox1").OLEFormat.Object ' <-- set my Object with "ComboBo1" drop-down

MsgBox MyDropDown.List(MyDropDown.ListIndex) '<-- display the value of the selected item 

End Sub
```

Below is a "cleaner" way to add a new `DropDown` to a `Worksheet` without using `ActiveSheet`, `Select` and `Selection` (just use fully qualified objects).

***Sub CreateFormControl* Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateFormControl()

Dim MyDropDown As DropDown
Dim i As Long

' set the drop-down object to the new created drop-down (replace "Sheet1" with your sheet's name)
Set MyDropDown = Worksheets("Sheet1").DropDowns.Add(0, 0, 100, 15)

' modify the drop-down properties
With MyDropDown
    .Name = "ComboBox1"

    .RemoveAllItems
    For i = 1 To 25
        .AddItem i
    Next i

    .OnAction = "ComboBox1_Change"
End With

End Sub
```